# nginx routing wss and https trafffic, listen on same port

Tags: nginx, websocket

I have nginx listening on port `<public_ip>:443`.
It gets both wss and https requests.

I am already redirecting `https` traffic to `localhost:3000`.

Is is possible to redirect `wss` to `localhost:10443`?

```
https://balbla.com:443 -> NGINX -> http://localhost:3000
wss://blabla.com:443 -> NGINX -> wss://localhost:10443
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible if you put websocket connect behind a URL. With below config, you can connect WSS at wss://hostname/websocket/:

```
location /websocket/ {
    proxy_pass ​http://localhost:10443;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 86400;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately its the same url/hostname

https://balbla.com:443 -> NGINX -> http://localhost:3000
wss://blabla.com:443 -> NGINX -> wss://localhost:10443